# How to create custom progress bar in angularjs Without Jquery-ui and without Boostrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, arrays

I am trying to create a progress bar in `Angularjs` but by using `jquery-ui` to create the progress bar. Now I am trying to achieve the same without `jquery-ui` and only in `angular`.

But it is not working. Below is my code, can you help me with it.

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
    <div progressbar="value"></div>
    <select ng-model="value" ng-options="item as item + '%' for item in items">
        <option value="">-- Select current progress --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**script**

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 10
    $scope.items = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}])
.directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'progress': '=progressbar'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.progressbar({
                value: $scope.progress
            })

            $scope.$watch(function() {
                $element.progressbar({value: $scope.progress})
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/A2CV5/639/

Comment: is that the code for your progress bar? if so, what's the problem with it?

Comment: here I used jquery-ui but I want to do without jquery-ui

Comment: OK ... so where's the code without jquery-ui? No point in posting code that works and asking for help with it, is there

Comment: how can achive without using jquery-ui libraries

Comment: I don't know how can create without using jquery-ui, can you give me logic or idea

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Comment: we can't achive with html css and angular js?

Comment: https://codepen.io/thathurtabit/pen/ymECf https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp https://html-online.com/articles/simple-progress-bar/ - there's literally millions of hits on google

Comment: samething in angular i am trying , how can i do in angular js

Comment: have you tried searching for `angularjs progress bar`

Comment: I searched with same keyword i got about code , can you help me above code converting html css angular without Jquery-ui

Comment: Try this [Angular progress bar](https://victorbjelkholm.github.io/ngProgress/#demo)

Comment: `can you help me above code converting html css angular without Jquery-ui` no

Comment: ngProgress not same as above code, totally deffrent, I want to work with above code without jquery-ui , how can i do

Answer (score 0):

You just have to play with some CSS and HTML to achieve this. The `$scope.value` will do all the magic. In my answer, I have used a link instead of controller since it is not practiced to use a controller for DOM manipulation. I have tried answering this in two way.

1. HTML 5 `<progress >` tag
2. Traditional way

I have taken this example from online source so the CSS can be anything as per your theme

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 10
    $scope.items = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}])
.directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'progress': '=progressbar'
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
           
        }
    }
}])
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }

article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }

#page-wrap { width: 490px; margin: 80px auto; }

body { background: #fff; text-align: center; color: #eee; font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; }
h1 { font-size: 42px; font-weight: 600; margin: 0 0 30px 0; }

pre {
 background: black;
 text-align: left;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto 30px auto; 
}

.meter { 
   height: 20px;  /* Can be anything */
   position: relative;
   margin: 60px 0 20px 0; /* Just for demo spacing */
   background: #555;
   -moz-border-radius: 25px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   padding: 10px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
   -moz-box-shadow   : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
   box-shadow        : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  }
  .meter > span {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
          -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
              border-top-right-radius: 8px;
           border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
       -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
           -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
               border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
   background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(
     linear,
     left bottom,
     left top,
     color-stop(0, rgb(43,194,83)),
     color-stop(1, rgb(84,240,84))
    );
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
     center bottom,
     rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
     rgb(84,240,84) 69%
    );
   -webkit-box-shadow: 
     inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
     inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 
     inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
     inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   box-shadow: 
     inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
     inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .meter > span:after, .animate > span > span {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
   background-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, 
         color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
         color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), 
         color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
         color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), 
         color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent)
      );
   background-image: 
    -moz-linear-gradient(
      -45deg, 
         rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
         transparent 25%, 
         transparent 50%, 
         rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
         rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
         transparent 75%, 
         transparent
      );
   z-index: 1;
   -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
   -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
   -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
          -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
              border-top-right-radius: 8px;
           border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
       -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
           -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
               border-top-left-radius: 20px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .animate > span:after {
   display: none;
  }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes move {
      0% {
         background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
         background-position: 50px 50px;
      }
  }
  
  .orange > span {
   background-color: #f1a165;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1a165, #f36d0a);
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #f1a165),color-stop(1, #f36d0a));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1a165, #f36d0a); 
  }
  
  .red > span {
   background-color: #f0a3a3;
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0, #f0a3a3),color-stop(1, #f42323));
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0a3a3, #f42323);
  }
  
  .nostripes > span > span, .nostripes > span:after {
   -webkit-animation: none;
   background-image: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
<!--HTML 5 way-->
<progress value="{{value}}" max="100" id="progressbar"></progress>

<!--Other  way-->
<div class="meter red">
 <span style="width: {{value}}%"></span>
</div>
    <!--<div progressbar="value"></div>-->
    <select ng-model="value" ng-options="item as item + '%' for item in items">
        <option value="">-- Select current progress --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 10
    $scope.items = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}])
.directive('progressbar', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            'progress': '=progressbar'
        },
        template: '<div style="background-color: red; height:60px; width:100%;"> <div  ng-style="style" style="background-color:blue; height:100%"></div> </div>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {


          $scope.$watch(function() {
                $scope.style = {"width": $scope.progress + "%"}
            })
        }
    }
}])
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mLyj1691/4/

Well, you get the idea...

Comment: Doing DOM operations in the controller is not a good idea and that too with the watcher, it an offense in Angular Application development.